# Looking for a way for border to fill the height of the last printed page

Tags: html, css, layout, printing, html-table

I am making a page for a client that generates a report that gets printed. There are a few caveats that mean I've ended up doing things in a not so ideal way.

The only problem I am left with is that on the very last page, the content does not fill the entire page and looks ugly.

[image: Report Example]

The current Structure of the HTML is as follows;

```
<div class="fixed bottom-0 text-center flex flex-col justify-between">
    footer content
</div>
first page (cover page w/ no border)
```

Then every page has the following structure...

```
<table class="page-break h-screen">
            @include('pdf.table-header')
            @include('pdf.table-footer')
            <tbody class="h-screen">
                <tr class="h-screen">
                    <td class="px-8 align-top h-screen text-sm">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The table footer is just empty with a fixed height to make way for the real footer with a fixed position.

All pages (tables) after page 1 are wrapped in the following div for the side borders..

```
<div class="border-primary border-l-8 border-r-8">
```

Any suggestions would be more than grateful

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out & I am posting it here if by any strange chance someone is using a similarly bad print layout.

I just had to add another div like this;

```
<div class="h-full border-primary border-l-8 border-r-8"></div>
```

After the last table and this would fill out any remaining space after the table on the last page.